# How to create dual HBox using javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2, uicontrol, hbox

I am trying to make controls for a media player. I have a slider and volume control which i wish to sit above another row of controls such as play mute etc at the bottom of the window.

I thought a good way to achieve this was creating a HBox that sits above another HBox, both aligned to the bottom in a javafx application.

I tried to use insets and margins to offset one from the other but i was not able to get them both to show.
Another attempt was to add the two HBox nodes to a VBox to get them vertically placed, but that was not successful either (i don't think it can be done this way).

Does anyone know how to implement this? or is there a better way to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

A GridPane might be what your looking for.

It acts similar to HBox and VBox, such as you can get creative and add other grids and boxes inside the main grid.